Trying to convert svg to React and react native components while supporting a number of customisations
const allSVGElementsRegexp = allSVGElements.map(
  (element) => new RegExp(`<${element}.*`),
);

const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "ts";
const TYPESCRIPT_KEY = "ts";

export function toStartCase(str: string) {
  const words = str.split("-");
  const res: string[] = [];
  words.forEach((word) => {
    word = word.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
    res.push(word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
  });
  return res.join("");
}

function toCamelCase(str: string) {
  const words = str.split("-");
  const res: string[] = [];
  words.slice(1).forEach((word) => {
    word = word.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
    res.push(word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1));
  });
  return [words[0]].concat(res).join("");
}

export interface TemplateOptions {
  addDefaultExport?: boolean;
  language: "ts" | "js";
  reactNative?: boolean;
  replaceValues?: {
    oldValue: string;
    newValue: string;
    addToInterface?: boolean;
    destructureFromProps?: boolean;
  }[];
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  /*  TODO:
  Add support for:
  - ref
  - memo
  - title, description props
   */
  spreadProps?: "start" | "end";
  interfaceExtend?: {
    from?: string;
    name: string;
  };
}

const defaultTemplateOptions: TemplateOptions = {
  addDefaultExport: true,
  language: TYPESCRIPT_KEY,
};

const reactTSImport = "import React, { FC%otherImports% } from 'react';";
const reactJSImport = "import React from 'react';";
const reactNativeImport = "import { %rnSvgImports% } from 'react-native-svg';";

const reactTSImportExtendingInterface = `import { %extend% } from "%import%";`;

const reactTSInterfaceWithoutExtend = "interface %name%Props { }";
const reactTSInterfaceWithExtend = "interface %name%Props extends %extend% { }";

const defaultExport = "export default %name%;";

const namedExportReactTS = `export const %name%: FC<%name%Props> = (props) => {
    return %componentContent%;
};`;

const namedExportReactJS = `export const %name% = (props) => {
    return %componentContent%;
};`;

const groupedByLanguage = {
  js: {
    import: reactJSImport,
    namedExport: namedExportReactJS,
    reactNativeImport,
    defaultExport,
  } as const,
  ts: {
    import: reactTSImport,
    reactNativeImport,
    namedExport: namedExportReactTS,
    interfaceWithoutExtend: reactTSInterfaceWithoutExtend,
    interfaceWithExtend: reactTSInterfaceWithExtend,
    importExtendingInterface: reactTSImportExtendingInterface,
    defaultExport,
  } as const,
} as const;

const XMLDeclarationRegex = /<\?xml\s+.*\?>/;
const HTMLCommentRegex = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/;

const getReactTemplate = (options: DeepPartial<TemplateOptions>) => {
  const template: string[] = [];
  const setToUse = groupedByLanguage[options.language ?? DEFAULT_LANGUAGE];

  template.push(setToUse.import);
  if (options.reactNative) {
    template.push(setToUse.reactNativeImport);
  }

  if (options.language === TYPESCRIPT_KEY) {
    if (
      options.interfaceExtend?.from &&
      options.interfaceExtend.from !== "react"
    ) {
      template.push(
        (setToUse as (typeof groupedByLanguage)["ts"]).importExtendingInterface,
      );
    }
    template.push(
      options.interfaceExtend?.name
        ? (setToUse as (typeof groupedByLanguage)["ts"]).interfaceWithExtend
        : (setToUse as (typeof groupedByLanguage)["ts"]).interfaceWithoutExtend,
    );
  }

  template.push(setToUse.namedExport);

  if (options.addDefaultExport) {
    template.push(setToUse.defaultExport);
  }

  return template.join("\n");
};

const attributesWithHyphen = allSVGAttributes.filter((attribute) =>
  attribute.includes("-"),
);


export const convertSvgToReact = async (
  svgContent: string,
  name: string,
  templateOptions: DeepPartial<TemplateOptions> = defaultTemplateOptions,
) => {
  // replace each of the disallowed attributes with their camelcase equivalents.
  attributesWithHyphen.forEach((attribute) => {
    if (svgContent.includes(attribute)) {
      svgContent = svgContent.replace(
        new RegExp(`${attribute}=`, "g"),
        toCamelCase(attribute) + "=",
      );
    }
  });
  if (templateOptions.title || templateOptions.description) {
    const titleRegex = /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/;
    const descriptionRegex = /<desc>(.*?)<\/desc>/;
    const svgOpenTagRegex = /<[sS]vg([^>]*)>/;

    let titleTag = "";
    let descTag = "";

    if (templateOptions.title) {
      titleTag = `<title>${templateOptions.title}</title>`;
    }

    if (templateOptions.description) {
      descTag = `<desc>${templateOptions.description}</desc>`;
    }

    const insertTags = titleTag + descTag;

    if (titleRegex.test(svgContent) && descriptionRegex.test(svgContent)) {
      svgContent = svgContent.replace(titleRegex, titleTag);
      svgContent = svgContent.replace(descriptionRegex, descTag);
    } else if (titleRegex.test(svgContent)) {
      svgContent = svgContent.replace(titleRegex, `${insertTags}`);
    } else if (descriptionRegex.test(svgContent)) {
      svgContent = svgContent.replace(descriptionRegex, `${insertTags}`);
    } else {
      svgContent = svgContent.replace(svgOpenTagRegex, `<svg$1>${insertTags}`);
    }
  }
  let fileContent = getReactTemplate(templateOptions);
  if (
    templateOptions.replaceValues &&
    templateOptions.replaceValues.length > 0
  ) {
    const propsToDestructure: string[] = [];
    const interfaceAdditions: string[] = [];

    templateOptions.replaceValues.forEach((item) => {
      if (!item) return;
      const { oldValue, newValue, addToInterface, destructureFromProps } = item;
      if (!oldValue || !newValue) return;
      const regex = new RegExp(`"${oldValue}"`, "g");
      svgContent = svgContent.replace(regex, `{${newValue}}`);

      if (addToInterface) {
        interfaceAdditions.push(`${newValue}: string;`);
      }

      if (destructureFromProps) {
        propsToDestructure.push(newValue);
      }
    });

    if (interfaceAdditions.length > 0) {
      const interfaceRegex = /interface %name%Props.*?\{.*?\}/s;
      const newInterface = fileContent
        .match(interfaceRegex)?.[0]
        .replace("}", `  ${interfaceAdditions.join("\n  ")}\n}`);
      if (newInterface) {
        fileContent = fileContent.replace(interfaceRegex, newInterface);
      }
    }

    if (propsToDestructure.length > 0) {
      const propsString = propsToDestructure.join(", ");
      fileContent = fileContent.replace(
        /export const %name%.*?\((props|)\).*?{/s,
        `export const %name%: FC<%name%Props> = ({ ${propsString}, ...props }) => {`,
      );
    }
  }

  fileContent = fileContent.replace(/%name%/g, toStartCase(name));
  fileContent = fileContent.replace(/%componentContent%/g, svgContent);

  if (templateOptions.reactNative) {
    const svgElementsUsed = allSVGElementsRegexp.reduce(
      (acc, curr, index) =>
        curr.test(fileContent) ? [...acc, allSVGElements[index]] : acc,
      [] as string[],
    );
    svgElementsUsed.forEach((element) => {
      fileContent = fileContent.replace(
        new RegExp(`<${element}`, "g"),
        `<${toStartCase(element)}`,
      );
      fileContent = fileContent.replace(
        new RegExp(`</${element}`, "g"),
        `</${toStartCase(element)}`,
      );
    });
    fileContent = fileContent.replace(
      /%rnSvgImports%/g,
      svgElementsUsed.map((element) => toStartCase(element)).join(", "),
    );
  }

  if (templateOptions.interfaceExtend?.name) {
    fileContent = fileContent.replace(
      /%extend%/g,
      templateOptions.interfaceExtend.name,
    );
  }

  if (templateOptions.interfaceExtend?.from) {
    if (
      templateOptions.interfaceExtend.from === "react" &&
      templateOptions.interfaceExtend.name
    ) {
      fileContent = fileContent.replace(/%import%/g, "");
      fileContent = fileContent.replace(
        /%otherImports%/g,
        `,${templateOptions.interfaceExtend.name}`,
      );
    } else {
      fileContent = fileContent.replace(
        /%import%/g,
        templateOptions.interfaceExtend.from,
      );
      fileContent = fileContent.replace(/%otherImports%/g, "");
    }
  } else {
    fileContent = fileContent.replace(/%otherImports%/g, "");
  }

  switch (templateOptions.spreadProps) {
    case "start":
      fileContent = fileContent?.replace(/(<[sS]vg)(.*?>)/g, (match, p1, p2) => `${p1} {...props}${p2}`);
      break;
    case "end":
      fileContent = fileContent?.replace(/(<[sS]vg)(.*?>)/g, (match, p1, p2) => `${p1}${p2.slice(0, -1)} {...props}>`);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  fileContent = fileContent.replace(XMLDeclarationRegex, "");
  fileContent = fileContent.replace(HTMLCommentRegex, "");
  fileContent = fileContent.replace(/return\s*\n/g, "return ");

  return prettier.format(fileContent, {
    parser: "typescript",
    plugins: [typescript, estree],
    semi: true,
    singleQuote: false,
    trailingComma: "none",
    printWidth: 100,
    tabWidth: 2,
    useTabs: false,
    jsxSingleQuote: false,
    bracketSpacing: true,
    arrowParens: "always",
  });
};

The aim of this tool is very similar to the existing Svgr tool. I'm making it because it adds a few small features that are missing in svgr which are not within the scope for svgr. The convertSvgToReact function is meant to be a core part of a simple tool that I'm making. The issue with it is that it seems to be non-cohesive. If one of the operations were to be out of order, a bunch of others would fail, sometimes silently. Is there a better way to organise this code? Any specific pattern that will ensure that the current and future features work without me having to go through each line and checking if the order of operations is right?

It is fragile because you are approaching it as a giant search and replace, when you are essentially writing a compiler. If you want it to be more robust, at the very least you can use an xml parser to pick out the nodes so you can avoid string matching issues. Then you can recurse over the tree or parts of it and extract it into your template.  No need to duplicate efforts, svgr uses babel-core for its traversal. In fact the best solution might be to write a babel plugin

Thank you for that insight. I'm essentially trying to make something like this playground: https://react-svgr.com/playground/ but with some additional customisation.
If I were to use babel-core or an xml parser, would I be able to convert the nodes from regular svg nodes to react-native ones?
